# In China airports, is passport needed on ticket?

Tags: tickets, passports

My girlfriend is flying from China to US. I booked her ticket through cheap tickets and the passport number was not requested. Does this need to be on the ticket, or is just her name on the ticket sufficient?

Comment: What is her citizenship? I don't know a definite answer, but it may be relevant.

Comment: I have never seen a passport number on a ticket.  The airline usually needs the passport number, presumably for the manifest, but they collect it as late as the time of check-in and, as far as I have ever seen, do not print it on the boarding pass or ticket (if there even is a paper ticket, which there almost never is these days).

Comment: Her citizenship is China.

Comment: I've never seen a passport number on a  ticket (some airlines request it, but it's not on the ticket).  I've flown in/out of China and the US.

Comment: @MarkMayo if the booking system asks for it online it's probably not for the ticket, but rather for the flight list info the US requests

Comment: She can provide her passport, of course. I was just wondering if it needs to be on the ticket or if the e-ticket with just her name is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Many countries will require API (Advanced Passenger Information) for passengers prior to departure or arrival.  This includes passport number.

Although this is not required at the time of booking tickets, it is required before checking in.  This can often be done over the counter or through online checkin.

See this [Emirates Airlines](http://www.emirates.com/english/help/faq/193410/What-is-Advanced-Passenger-Information-Why-do-I-need-to-provide-it) page as an example of why and [how](http://www.emirates.com/english/help/faq/198344/i-am-travelling-to-a-country-that-requires-advanced-passenger-information-api-can-i-still-use-onl) an airline that collects this information.

> If you are travelling to one of these countries, you can still use online check-in where available, provided that all of the relevant passport information for you and anyone travelling with you has been completed. If any passport information is missing or incorrect, you can add or edit that information through the online check-in system.

**Update:**

China is a country on the list that requires API.

USA is a country that will require additional information.

Airlines themselves don't *need* your passport number, they only need something to identify you.  Most domestic flights in many countries won't even require you to have a passport.

Comment: She can provide her passport, of course. I was just wondering if it needs to be on the ticket or if the e-ticket with just her name is sufficient.

Comment: API is only required by Governments, not by the airlines themselves, so no the passport number is not required to be on the ticket by any law I know of

Comment: Most airlines will say that the name on the ticket must match exactly the name on your passport

Comment: @AlexGain No, it isn't required on the ticket (and technically, an airline ticket has no space for a passport number to be provided, although it could go in the PNR).